# Custom regular expression pattern

Tags: php, preg-split

What's the right pattern to obtain something like that using preg_split.

Input:

```
Src.[VALUE1] + abs(Src.[VALUE2])
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Src.[VALUE1] 
    [1] => Src.[VALUE2]
)
```

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to `preg_split`?  It doesn't seem appropriate in this case.

Comment: hi, because in my case I use preg_* but I can change, if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split), using [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) makes more sense in this case:

```
preg_match_all('/\w+\.\[\w+\]/', $str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
```

Result of `$matches`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Src.[VALUE1]
    [1] => Src.[VALUE2]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should be fine

```
Src\.\[[^\]]+\]
```

But instead of `preg_split` I'd suggest using `preg_match_all`

```
$string = 'Src.[VALUE1] + abs(Src.[VALUE2])';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/Src\.\[[^\]]+\]/', $string, $matches);
```

All matches you're looking for will be bound to `$matches[0]` array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `preg_match_all` is what you want. This works -

```
$string = "Src.[VALUE1] + abs(Src.[VALUE2])";
$regex = "/Src\.\[.*?\]/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
/*
    OUTPUT
*/
array
  0 => string 'Src.[VALUE1]' (length=12)
  1 => string 'Src.[VALUE2]' (length=12)
```